# FileNotFoundError on subprocess.call() in Python

Tags: python, r, subprocess

I am trying to run R script using Python. I using subprocess.call function to achieve this. As suggested in other posts I have tried these different codes:

Code1

```
subprocess.call(['Rscript', '--vanilla', 'C:/Users/siddh/Downloads/R_script_BCA.R'])
```

Code 2

```
subprocess.Popen(['Rscript', '--vanilla', 'C:/Users/siddh/Downloads/R_script_BCA.R'])
```

Error for both

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Code 3

```
subprocess.Popen('Rscript --vanilla C:/Users/siddh/Downloads/R_script_BCA.R', shell=True)
```

Running code 3 just shows the following and nothing happens

```
<Popen: returncode: None args: 'Rscript --vanilla C:/Users/siddh/Downloads/R...>
```

The following code worked fine when used in command prompt/PowerShell

```
Rscript --vanilla "C:/Users/siddh/Downloads/R_script_BCA.R"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if Rscript wasn't found in the `PATH` environ variable. Put the full path to Rscript, sort of:

```
subprocess.call([
    r'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1\bin\Rscript',    # put here the path to your Rscript
    '--vanilla', 
    'C:/Users/siddh/Downloads/R_script_BCA.R'
])
```

Or add the path before running `subprocess.call`:

```
import os
os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + r'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1\bin'   # replace with your real path to Rscript
```

To see if you have or not the path to Rscript in the `PATH` inside of the running python:

```
import os
for p in os.environ['PATH'].split(';'):
    print(p)
```

To find the path to your Rscript in PowerShell:

```
Get-Command Rscript | Select-Object Source
```

Comment: Putting the full path to Rscript worked. Thank you!